# Php ajax file upload is stopped working in safari

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I am using ajax file upload which was working fine before. But suddenly it has stopped working into safari browser.
Here is the code I am using.

```
$('#addEditCategoryButton').click(function() {
            var formData = new FormData($('#editCategoryForm')[0]);
            if($("#editCategoryForm").valid()){
                var url = window.parent.location.pathname;
                var urlPath = url.split("/").pop();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "categories-operations.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#json-overlay-2").show();
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data != 'failed') {
                            if(urlPath != 'manage-categories.php')
                            {
                                location.href = 'manage-categories.php';
                            } else {
                                table.api().ajax.url( 'categories-operations.php?action=fetchData&catIdUnder=0').load();
                                $("#addNewEmployeeModal").modal('hide');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $("#installMessage").show();
                        }
                        $("#json-overlay-2").hide();
                    }        
                });
            }
            $(document).find("label.error").css('color', 'red');
        });
```

Please help me on this. When I remove contentType: false,processData: false then it works.

Comment: What does it mean 'it has stopped working'? Do you have any errors?

Comment: No it's not even throwing any error but page keeps on loading in safari.